# jQuery DataTables get all table rows data and send through post as array

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, datatables

What I want to do is get all the data from the table and send it as a autoincremented multi-dimensional array with ajax using the post method. When it gets to the server it should be like:

```
$_POST  -|-- ['Key1'] = 'value1'   <---This is from an HTML input
         |-- ['Key2'] = 'value2'   <---This is from an HTML input
         |-- ['tabledata']--| -- [0]-| -- ['column1'] = 'value from cell'            
                            |        | -- ['column2'] = 'value from cell'
                            | -- [1]-| -- ['column1'] = 'value from cell'
                                     | -- ['column2'] = 'value from cell'
```

[0] and [1] are just autoincremented numbers generated when a new array object is created representing first and second row in this case.
 Here is a js fiddle with what I got so far (it returns array but not the way I need them) https://jsfiddle.net/v2quhwb8/2/ with the JS:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
   var myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
     responsive: true
   });



   var testData = myTable.data().toArray();

   $('#myButton').on('click', function() {

     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'json',
       url: 'page/postTest.php',
       data: testData,
       success: function(response) {
         // console.log('Server response', response);
       }
     });

   });


 });
```

Comment: what is `key1` and `key2` and what are its values?

Comment: Key1 and Key2 come from 2 other inputs I'm sending data from.

Comment: your `['ajax'][0]`  must be array of column values? and here is `[0]` a key or a index?

Comment: No its ['ajax'][0]['colum-name']['cellvalue'] , the 0 is just the index of the array that represents the first row.

Comment: now the default is ` ['ajax'][0]` is a array of just values.. So you want a ` ['ajax'][0]` to be a object and with key value structure.. right ?

Comment: No ['ajax'] is a multidimensional array in my representation... the 0 is just the first number in the autoincremented index. What I want is inside that ['0'] array to pass the values of the first row like ['column name'] => ['cell value'] for all columns.

Comment: Sorry it must have been confusing when I put ['ajax']. The whole $_POST comes from AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own answer:

`data: testData`  in `$.ajax({...` changed to `data: {data: testData}` and it returns the multidimensional array that I need in PHP `$_POST`. Also what I asked before was an associative array like the backend idiot that I am because apparently, they don't exist in javascript, my bad guys.

What you will get in PHP is something like `$_POST['data'][0][0]['cell value']`, the first zero is the row from first to last, the second zero represents the cells from left to right. I guess I'll have to work with this somehow. I updated https://jsfiddle.net/v2quhwb8/4/